# Linux ssh/terminal program with built-in file browser

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, file-management, scp

I've moved back to using Linux after a stint on Windows. While there, I had discovered and heavily used MobaXterm for ssh (and the occasional X session). The standout feature for me was that when connected to a remote server, it would provide a file browser of the remote server beside the terminal (with full desktop integration). When running multiple ssh sessions as I do, this was an unexpected productivity boost (rather than having to drop out to a local terminal and scp, or open up a separate file browser window).

Is there anything comparable for Linux? I'm well aware that I can use nautilus to mount an ssh server as a 'filesystem', but I'm looking for something that more tightly ties the terminal to the file browser.

Answer (score -1):

> rather than having to drop out to a local terminal and scp, or open up a separate file browser window

The tiling terminals or window managers are good alternative. I use **Terminator** and opening new Tile with local shell is one click and transfering files using `scp` is just a line of code.

Workflow combining terminal window with file browser might sound like an interesting idea, but learning how to use terminal effectively that you will not need the file browser is probably better way to go.